# How to publish docker container output as Build artifact in Azure Devops

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am migrating my company's codebase from GitLab to Azure Devops. I have a Data Science project that uses two docker images sequentially:

1. Image #1 is used to build a docker container in which a python script runs - `similarity.py` which is a Machine Learning model.
2. Image #2 is used to build a docker container in which an API gets published. This api *uses* the trained machine learning model that was published in Image one.

The two images are seperate because #1 doesn't need all API dependencies, and #2 doesn't need the build dependencies for training the ML model. However, Image #2 *needs the trained ML model from image #1 as input*

In GitLab, I achieved the above use-case in three steps:

1. In the `prebuild_master_step` I build Image #1.
2. In the `transform_master step`, I use the built image from step 1 to run a
   script (similarity.py) which produces output (a trained ml-model). I
   publish the `data/` folder as artifact (data folder is where the
   trained ML model resides after running `similarity.py`).
3. In the build_master step, I create a dependency to the previous
   step (transform_master), and I build Image #2.

This is the code I'm using to achieve abovementioned steps in Gitlab:

```
image: docker:stable

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE_CONTENTFUL_API: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/contentful_api:latest
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE_CONTENTFUL_APP: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/contentful_app:latest

prebuild_master:
  stage: prebuild
  #Build Image #1 and push it to container registry
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -f Dockerfile .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE_CONTENTFUL_APP
  only:
    refs:
      - master

transform_master:
  #Get image one from container registry - use it to run similarity.py. Publish data/ folder
  #From docker container (in which trained ML model is stored) as artifact.
  image: $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE_CONTENTFUL_APP
  stage: transform
  script:
    - python similarity.py
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - data/
  only:
    refs:
  - master

build_master:
  #Use the artifact published in previous step as dependency to build Image two, the API.
  stage: build
  dependencies:
    - transform_master
  script:
    - docker build -f DockerfileAPI .
  only:
    refs:
      - master
```

Now I'm trying to achieve a similar process in Azure Devops. The problem I'm running into is: **I don't know how to get files out of a docker container (which was used to run a script), in Azure Devops.** My Azure Devops pipeline looks as follows:

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'xxx'
  containerRegistry: 'xxx'
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  tagImage: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  #Pre-Build Image vars
  dockerfilePreBuildPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  imageRepositoryPreBuild: 'DS/contentfulapi_prebuild_img'
  #API Image vars
  dockerfileAPIPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DockerfileAPI'
  imageRepositoryAPI: 'DS/contentfulapi_api_img'


stages:
  - stage: Prebuild
    displayName: Pre-build model
    jobs:
      - job: Prebuild
        displayName: Prebuild
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Pre-build model
            inputs:
              command:  build
              repository: $(imageRepositoryPreBuild)
              dockerfile: $(dockerfilePreBuildPath)
              tags: $(tagImage)
          - script: |
              docker run ds/contentfulapi_prebuild_img:$(tagImage) python similarity.py
            displayName: Run similarity.py and save model
          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            displayName: Publish data directory in pipeline
            inputs:
              targetPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/data
              artifactName: DataDir
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build API
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: DataDir
          - task: CopyFiles@2
            displayName: Copy Artifact into new build workspace
            inputs:
              sourceFolder: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/DataDir
              targetFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/data
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Build API
            inputs:
              command: build
              repository: $(imageRepositoryAPI)
              dockerfile: $(dockerfileAPIPath)
              tags: $(tagImage)
          - script: cd data && ls
```

First, I run similarity.py in the `Prebuild` stage: `docker run ds/contentfulapi_prebuild_img:$(tagImage) python similarity.py` Then, I'm trying to Publish a pipeline artifact in pre-build stage (`PublishPipelineArtifact@1`) and consume this artifact in the `Build` stage (`CopyFiles@2`). However, the `Build.Sourcesdirectory` I'm using in the `PublishPipelineArtifact` task is the incorrect directory (it only contains my source code).

TL;DR:

**How can I refer to/copy docker container output from one stage in an Azure Devops Pipeline in another stage of the pipeline?**

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve issue by adding a docker cp command. Will not accept this answer as I believe cleaner ways (of which I do not know at present time) exist to solve this use-case.

```
  #Run similarity.py inside docker container so that model can be saved
  - script: |
      docker run --name pre_build_docker_ct ds/contentfulapi_prebuild_img:$(tagImage) python similarity.py
    displayName: Run similarity.py and save model
  #Capture model output and copy to Build.SourcesDirectory
  - script : |
      docker cp pre_build_docker_ct:/home/project/contentful/data .
    displayName: Copy container output into Build.SourcesDirectory
  #Publish Build.SourcesDirectory as artifact
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: Publish data directory in pipeline
    inputs:
      targetPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/data
      artifactName: DataDir
```